# Difference between USING and ON in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

It doesn't seem like there's a difference between:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
  FROM table a JOIN table2 b
 USING (col3)
```

and

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
  FROM table a JOIN table2 b
    ON (a.col3 = b.col3)
```

Or is there? (of course other than with `ON` I can use different column names)

Comment: A similar MySQL question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370268/whats-the-difference-between-using-and-on-in-table-joins/10250985#10250985

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference for me is that you can paint yourself into a corner with the USING clause:

```
CREATE TABLE roster (mgrid INTEGER, empid INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE emp (empid INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO roster VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO roster VALUES (1,11);
INSERT INTO roster VALUES (1,12);
INSERT INTO roster VALUES (2,20);
INSERT INTO roster VALUES (2,21);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (10, 'John');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (11, 'Steve');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (12, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (20, 'Ann');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (21, 'George');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, 'Pete');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2, 'Sally');

SELECT r.mgrid, e2.name, e1.empid, e1.name
  FROM roster r JOIN emp e1 USING(empid)
                JOIN emp e2 ON r.mgrid = e2.empid;
```

In the above select, you get an ora-25154, "column part of USING clause cannot have a qualifier".

If you remove the e1.empid qualifier, as in:

```
SELECT r.mgrid, e2.name, empid, e1.name
  FROM roster r JOIN emp e1 USING(empid)
                JOIN emp e2 ON r.mgrid = e2.empid;
```

You get an ORA-00918 error, "column ambiguously defined".

You have to use:

```
SELECT r.mgrid, e2.name, e1.empid, e1.name
  FROM roster r JOIN emp e1 ON r.empid = e1.empid
                JOIN emp e2 ON r.mgrid = e2.empid;
```

The example is contrived, but when I was first exploring the join syntax I ran into this exact problem in a real situation. I have avoided the USING clause ever since. There is no advantage with the USING clause other than a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

Not much.  Of course, ON allows this, which USING does not:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2
  FROM table a JOIN table2 b
    ON (a.col3 = b.col4)
                      ^
```

This is the ANSI join syntax, it is not unique to Oracle.

Comment: Well, Oracle didn't support ANSI syntax in older versions of their DB.

Comment: True, up to 8i I think.  But they have done for about 12 years now!

Comment: It's a new feature from 9i, which is 10 years old already. This makes me feel so old...

Answer (score 1):

`ON` includes all the columns that are being joined from the joining tables, so that you have two or more of the same column types in the resulting dataset.

But `USING` removes duplicates of the columns that are being joined to leave one of that type,
which makes it similar to a natural join (except they don't have to have the same name) as highlighted in this [question on natural joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696383/difference-between-natural-join-and-inner-join)

`USING` can be useful ;) for doing inserts with a subquery that joins tables (in my case flattening tables for a data warehouse star schema, where I only wanted one of the id columns).

Answer (score -1):

No. If you leave the syntax behind, there is no difference on those exact two sentences.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: can you elaborate? How can those sentences yield different result sets?

Comment: `USING` removes the duplicate columns that were matched in the `USING` clause. `ON` doesn't.