# MySQL NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN vs LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, outer-join, natural-join

If I have the following situations:

```
**table 1
person| money
    A | 2
    B | 10
-------------


**table 2 
person| cars
    A | 3
    C | 10
```

### ---------------

What is the difference between the two?

`SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN table2;`

produces:

```
person| money |cars
    A | 2     |3
    B | 10    |NULL
---------------
```

vs

`SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table 2 ON person`

Comment: The natural join will infer the join columns and remove the duplicate join column from the result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between natural join and inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696383/difference-between-natural-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: I don't think your non-`NATURAL` version is valid syntax. Did you mean to use `USING` rather then `ON`? e.g. `SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 USING ( person )` ? Also the space in `table 2` appears to be a typo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I don't agree it is a duplicate: e.g. you can't answer that other question without using range variables (which is kinda the point of natural join, BTW), whereas the OP hasn't used range variables in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have typos in your non-`NATURAL` version and what you are comparing is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL LEFT OUTER JOIN table2;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 USING ( person );
```

First, I would expect the result of both to be equal.**

Second, I don't see any point in the non-`NATURAL`/`USING` version in your case because you only have the one column in common and they are consistently named.

** I was going to qualify with "relationally speaking" (e.g. column order and row order not being relevant) but `OUTER JOIN` is expressly designed to generate nulls, which have no place in the relational model! Therefore, I recommend you avoid `OUTER JOIN` entirely and take another approach e.g. it seems entirely reasonable to use `0` (cars) as a default value for persons who have no entry in `table2`:

```
SELECT person, money, cars 
  FROM table1 
       NATURAL JOIN table2
UNION
SELECT person, money, 0 AS cars 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE person NOT IN ( SELECT person FROM table2 );
```