# Clarity on concept of JOIN in SQL needed

Tags: mysql, sql, join, natural-join

So the various type of joins we come across in SQL are :

1.JOIN

2.NATURAL JOIN

3.INNER JOIN

4.OUTER JOIN(LEFT, RIGHT, FULL)

5.CROSS JOIN

I need clarity in understanding what is the difference between JOIN, NATURAL JOIN and CROSS JOIN

At w3schools.com I used the JOIN and NATURAL JOIN query and got the following results

1.Query for JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers;
```

[Output of the JOIN query(Postal Code and Country Column can't be seen but they're there)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQ4G.png)

2.Query for NATURAL JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
NATURAL JOIN Customers;
```

[Output of Natural Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSVWE.png)

I'm a beginner and I'm not getting clear with concept of JOIN and NATURAL JOIN keyword since the material on internet is not sufficient or if it's there doesn't clear the confusion I have between these two keywords.

I can't understand why the number of records fetched by the 2 keywords are so different.Please explain in deep what's happening here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696383/difference-between-natural-join-and-inner-join

Comment: Forget about `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is a blight on the language.  Learn about inner joins, outer joins, and cross joins.

Comment: Yeah so Inner join and Join are same thing or different ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOIN

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders o
  JOIN customers c
    ON o.customerid = c.customerid
```

Result

```
orderid, orderdate,  customerid, customerid, customername
10248,   1996-04-07, 1,          1,          Alfreds Futterkitse
10248,   1996-04-07, 2,          2,          Ana Trujillo
10248,   1996-04-07, 3,          3,          Antonio Moreno
10248,   1996-04-07, 4,          4,          Around the Horn
10248,   1996-04-07, 5,          5,          Berglunds snabbkop
```

The repeated column is avoided in NATURAL JOIN

NATURAL JOIN

```
 SELECT *
   FROM orders o
NATURAL JOIN customers c
```

Result

```
customerid, orderid, orderdate,  customername
1,          10248,   1996-04-07, Alfreds Futterkitse
2,          10248,   1996-04-07, Ana Trujillo
3,          10248,   1996-04-07, Antonio Moreno
4,          10248,   1996-04-07, Around the Horn
5,          10248,   1996-04-07, Berglunds snabbkop
```

Since you selected *, both customerid in orders and customers will display in JOIN but in NATURAL JOIN, it will only be one customerid column that will be displayed.

Comment: You say that but I don't see CustomerID column repeated in case of JOIN .Is it that they've not shown ? I know what you're saying is totally correct but the output is causing the confusion

Comment: Also why there are only 196 records in case of Natural join but in case of Join there are like 178...(some number) records?

Comment: Please see edited answer above with samples. With regards to your records, maybe it was affected by not using ON clause on your query for JOIN.