# Ambiguity in the SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables: table `customer` consists of information about customers and table `payment` consists of information about payments. Primary key `customer_id` in the `customer` table is a foreign key in the table `payment_id`. The following two queries return identical results:

```
SELECT
  payment.customer_id,
  last name,
  amount
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id

SELECT
  customer.customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
```

The only difference between the queries is in the first argument in the `SELECT` clause: `payment.customer_id` vs `customer.customer_id`. As the `customer_id` is the column on which the tables are joining on, the distinction between `payment.customer_id` and `customer.customer_id` seems meaningless. However, if I try to omit the table in the query:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
```

I receive

> [42702] ERROR: column reference "customer_id" is ambiguous

Could you please describe where is ambiguity in the query?

Comment: How can DBMS engine know which (common) column do you prefer without any addressing to individual table(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because two columns match using the equality test, does not mean that they have the same value.

The two columns could be different types eg integer and float, or numeric etc.

Or they could be `citext` [which does case insensitive comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html) (one table could have `'RedRum'` and other `'redruM'`).

often the join condition might not be a strict equality (eg a network range comparison, or prefix match)

In all these cases which table you use for the result column is significant.

if you're doing an outer join table name is again significant.

Postgresql does not know when `=` means that the table can be implied and when it cannot, it requires it always.

Rule of thumb,  when joining tables specify the table of every column you use in the query.  that way things won't break if someone adds some columns to the other table.

Answer (score 4):

The error means there are two columns have same name `customer_id`, let DB engine didn't know Which one column do you want to query.

You need to explicitly tell the DB engine the name of the column you want to query.

Tables may be added a new column after table has been created, the new column may be the same as the old column name if you didn't clearly specify `SELECT` table columns of the query in the selection the will be an error on your original query.

Here is some suggestion for you

- You can give query table an Alias name, let your query Clearer.
- Clearly specify `SELECT` table columns of the query in the selection from tables name, because of tables

If `last_name` column in `payment` table and `amount` column in `customer`

you can do this.

```
SELECT
  c.customer_id,
  p.last_name,
  c.amount
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN payment p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question by omitting the table in the select statement. By not specifying it, SQL doesn't know Which table is `customer_id` referring to.

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please describe where is ambiguity in the query?

Logically there is no ambiguity in the query, as both the columns must have the same values. However, an ambiguity may appear when you use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO customer (customer_id, last_name) VALUES
(1, 'Smith'),
(2, 'Jones');

INSERT INTO payment (customer_id, amount) VALUES
(1, 100);

SELECT
    customer.customer_id,
    payment.customer_id,
    last_name,
    amount
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id

 customer_id | customer_id | last_name | amount 
-------------+-------------+-----------+--------
           1 |           1 | Smith     |    100
           2 |             | Jones     |       
(2 rows)
```

The parser just follows general rules and does not analyse a query to find out when a potential ambiguity can come to light.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to always prefix your column with table/subquery alias.

But in your case(only PK/FK names are shared among both tables) you could also use `USING` clause:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM customer
JOIN payment USING(customer_id);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b3fd467540fcd84ed97cfd51cc702ea8)**

---

There is also third possible solution, but I strongly recommend not to use it:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM customer
NATURAL JOIN payment
```

Comment: I strongly recommend the `NATURAL JOIN` 'solution' because I consider it best practice to avoid duplicate columns rather than using range variables to work around the problems they cause.

Comment: @onedaywhen I prefer to avoid natural join, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696399/5070879) you can find some reasons why.

Comment: @onedaywhen Feel free to use any approach that suits you best. In my opinion `NATURAL JOIN` does not solve anything plus it could cause more problems in the future. My advice is simple: don't be lazy (use table aliases for each column and it will pay off in the long run).

Comment: First, what you call "table aliases" are actually range variables. The idea is they 'range over' the rows in the table and represent a row, not a table. Therefore, "table aliases" is most inappropriate. Second, range variables were the workaround to the problem of duplicate columns generated by pre-1992 join types. The problem was fixed in 1992 with `NATURAL JOIN`, a superior join type that replaces older join types...

Comment: If I chose to use a pre-1992 join type, it would generate duplicate columns, which I'd then need to use range variables to workaround. Instead, I choose to avoid the problem entirely by using `NATURAL JOIN`. Your accusation of laziness is well wide of the mark.

Comment: @onedaywhen "NATURAL JOIN, a superior join type that replaces older join types"  `NATURAL JOIN` is not "superior" at all. I prefer EIBTI rule simply because it is easier to maintain in the long run. If you feel that natual join is strongly recommended I accept that. Based on my experience I wouldn't use it on production code(simply when schema drifts and new column is added with the same name) many bad things may happen.

Comment: @onedaywhen If I had to specify each table columns with CTE, as you proposed, then I would simply use `JOIN ON`  and fully qualified names. `consider that adding new columns to an existing table is probably not a good idea in principle` Still I cannot agree with that statement. Views may be good if you read only date otherwise you have to do some clumsy things like making columns nullable or add triggers.

Comment: Noting a table is analogous to a type (and, at a stretch, its key is its interface), take a look at the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). But principle aside, if doing something in practice (adding a column to a table...) is a breaking change (...breaks a customer's query) then doing so is reckless. How does one 'extend' a table while avoiding nulls and triggers? Extending table has same key as extended table and with new attribute. I think the closest to 'principle' here is [6NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form).

Answer (score 1):

Legacy joins such as `INNER JOIN` create duplicate columns. Using `INNER JOIN` in your query generates two columns named `customer_id`. The SQL language has a workaround for this: you must prefix the column with a range variable, as others have suggested here (though using the misleading term 'table alias').

Thankfully, the SQL language also has a fix for this problem: `NATURAL JOIN` creates no duplicate columns, therefore you don't need to disambiguate them:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM customer
NATURAL JOIN payment
```

Joins that produce duplicate columns remain because nothing is ever removed from the SQL language (the "shackles of compatibility"). But you don't need any join other than `NATURAL JOIN`.

The idea is that your data element names mean the same thing throughout your data dictionary e.g. `amount` means one thing (pertaining to payments) and one things only (there is no `amount` that pertains to customers or any other type).

Sometimes you may need to 'project away' columns you don't want to participate in `NATURAL JOIN` e.g.

```
WITH
C AS ( SELECT customer_id, last_name FROM customer ),
P AS ( SELECT customer_id, amount FROM payment )
SELECT
  customer_id,
  last_name,
  amount
FROM C 
NATURAL JOIN P
```

This also 'defends' your code e.g. in the unlikely event of someone adding a `last_name` attribute to payments.