# PostgreSQL equivalent of Pandas outer merge

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, merge, outer-join

I am trying to do in Postgres the equivalent of Pandas outer merge, in order to outer merge two tables.

Table `df_1` contains these data:

[image]

Table `df_2` contains these data:

[image]

So Table `df_1` has one extra column (`random_id`) than `df_2`. Also, job_id **1711418** and worker_id **45430** exist in both `df_1` and `df_2`.

If I use the "outer merge" method in Pandas:
`df_1.merge(df_2, on=['job_id', 'worker_id'], how='outer')`, I would get the ideal result as shown below:

[image]

However, I wasn't able to find a SQL (postgres) equivalent of that Pandas outer merge method.

I've tried running the following query:

```
select *
from df_1
full outer join df_2
   on df_1.job_id = df_2.job_id 
  and df_1.worker_id = df_2.worker_id
```

However, the result generated 2 extra duplicate columns called `job_id_duplicate_column_name_1` and `worker_id_duplicate_column_name_1` which I don't want:
[image]

Could anyone help suggest a query method that can achieve the same as outer merge method in Pandas?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Default Pandas merge/join is a "natural" SQL join. Read the documentation before you use functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between natural join and inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696383/difference-between-natural-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: @philipxy, natural join doesn't work in my case because it only joins on matching records. In my use case there are some records that are distinct between df_1 and df_2 and I want to preserve all of them in the result.

Comment: I meant natural full join. I missed that the Q&A I found was only for natural inner vs plain inner rather than for natural vs plain for both inner & outer. Your special case of tables means you could do a natural right join. Also you'd need to map NULLs to NaN. Between the special case & NaN you might want to use UNION etc as in the accepted answer. I was focusing on natural vs plain; I'm not certain at this moment that that's the result you actually want. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: `df_1.merge(df_2, on=[LIST], how='outer')` is like SQL `df_1 full join df_2 using (LIST)`; when LIST is all common columns that's `df_1 natural full join df_2`. Only one copy of each USING or common column is returned. (Unmatched rows extended by NULLs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a UNION to me, not a JOIN:

```
select job_id, worker_id, random_id
from df_1
union all
select job_id, worker_id, 'NaN'
from df_2 d2
where not exists (select *
                  from df_1 d1
                  where d1.job_id = d2.job_id
                    and d1.worker_id = d2.worker_id)
```

The second part of the union returns all rows from `df_2` that don't exist in `df_1`

An alternative would be to use `EXCEPT` to get the rows from df_2 that don't exist in `df_1`

```
select job_id, worker_id, random_id
from df_1
union all
select job_id, worker_id, 'NaN'
from 
(
  select job_id, worker_id
  from df_2 d2
  except
  select job_id, worker_id
  from df_1
) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c76cd9912e7b2ee89f744197f570e8d)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! Your suggestion works as intended. I am gonna take some time to learn more about this approach.