# USING clause of MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

Does USING clause in MYSQL cause error when join column is referenced using alias elsewhere?
Is this true for all databases or specific functionality ?

EG :

```
 SELECT productCode,productName,textDescription 
 FROM products INNER JOIN productlines USING (productline)
 WHERE products.productline="Motorcycles";
```

I have read in one of the answers that it throws error but I didn't get one using MYSQL.
Ref : [USING Keyword vs ON clause - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750152/using-keyword-vs-on-clause-mysql)

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly so one can get exactly what you want to achieve :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask