# a clarification regarding a query

Tags: sql

why did they in the below query, in the inner join section wrote USING not on?

```sql
SELECT
   COALESCE(department_name, '-') department,
   COALESCE(job_title,'-') job,
   COUNT(*) ,
   SUM(salary) salary
FROM
   employees
INNER JOIN departments USING (department_id)
INNER JOIN jobs USING (job_id)
GROUP BY
   CUBE(department_name,job_title)
ORDER BY
   department_name ASC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Answer (score 1):

**USING clause**

- The USING clause specifies which columns to test for equality when
  two tables are joined. It can be used instead of an ON clause in the
  JOIN operations that have an explicit join clause.

  The columns listed in the USING clause must be present in both of the
  two tables being joined.

  The USING clause will be transformed to an ON clause that checks for
  equality between the named columns in the two tables.

USING Clause is used to match only one column when more than one column matches.

syntax and example:

[USING Keyword vs ON clause - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750152/using-keyword-vs-on-clause-mysql)

Comment: ok, thanks.  may i ask why did we add (=) in the subquery, in the following query:   SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    salary, 
    department_id
FROM
    employees e
WHERE
    salary > (SELECT 
            AVG(salary)
        FROM
            employees
        WHERE
            department_id = e.department_id)
ORDER BY 
    department_id , 
    first_name , 
    last_name;