# MySql query returning entire table with possible values from a second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

event_categories containing:

> event_category_id, event_category

Sample data:

```
1, Tennis
2, Volleyball
3, Boxing
4, Skating
```

Then I have a table that joins users that might possibly be linked to any of these categories.

users_event_categories containing

> user_id, event_category_id

Sample data:

```
1223, 2
1223, 4
5998, 2
```

I need a query that returns ALL event categories, and returns if a user has that category linked.

So if I query with the user_id 1223 my result would be:

```
1, Tennis, 0
2, Volleyball, 1
3, Boxing, 0
4, Skating, 1
```

Or a query with user_id 4444 would return:

```
1, Tennis, 0
2, Volleyball, 0
3, Boxing, 0
4, Skating, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work if you only want data about one particular user

```
select ec.event_category_id, ec.event_category, if(uec.user_id is null, 0, 1) 
from event_categories ec 
    left join users_event_categories uec
        on uec.event_category_id = ec.event_category_id and uec.user_id = 1223
```

Comment: You were faster :) Here's a fiddle with the working solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b7143/8/0

Comment: I was unaware that it is possible to do an additional AND statement with a join statement. Also, interestingly replacing on uec.event_category_id = ec.event_category_id with USING(event_category_id) does not work.

Comment: This is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using

Comment: @jbrosi Was just looking at your jsfiddle as well. It only works with the id 1223. Another id skips some results.

Comment: @MichaelFrey sorry my fault, fixed the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b7143/22

Answer (score 0):

```
select tn2.user_id,event_category,count(event_category) as total from table_name1 tn1
inner join table_name2 tn2 on tn1.event_category_id = tn2.event_category_id
where tn2.user_id = 4444
group by event_category
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this only returns the category where the users are linked to, and excludes all others.