# Difference between 'on' and 'using' in theta join

Tags: sql

I was studying Theta join. In join condition, we can use 'on' or 'using' for specifying common columns in two or more tables. Now how would I know If I am to use 'on' or 'using' ?

Example

> Find customer names and their loan amounts (loan and borrower are two relations)

Table layout:

```
loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)!
borrower (customer_name, loan_number)!
```

So what is the difference between this:

```
select b.customer_name, l.amount 
from borrower b join loan l 
on b.loan_number = l.loan_number"
```

and this:

```
select b.customer_name, l.amount 
from borrower b join loan l 
using (loan_number)
```

Comment: Don't you mean ON or WHERE? I don't see how you could use USING with a theta join. Can you show us an example?

Comment: Find customer names and their loan amounts.

there are 2 relations: loan and borrower

● loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
● borrower (customer_name, loan_number)

■ select b.customer_name, l.amount 
from borrower b join loan l 
on b.loan_number = l.loan_number

■ select b.customer_name, l.amount 
from borrower b join loan l 
using (loan_number)

Comment: I presume it is MYSQL?

Comment: read my question now. I have edited it with an example.

Comment: You can use USING when the columns in the two join tables have the same name. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11367066/379855