# Build a left join query with using() instead of on()

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, query-builder

How do I create a query that joins with `using()` instead of `on`?

I have this:

```
$games = DB::table('games')
    ->leftJoin('game_info', 'game_id')
    ->get();
```

I would like it to build a query that looks like this:

```
select * from games left join game_info using(game_id);
```

Comment: Could maybe try `DB::table("games")->select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM games LEFT JOIN game_info USING(game_id)"))->get();`, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no easy way to make join this way if you don't want to create raw query. However looking at SQL documentation and after quick look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using) `using` works the same as you defined in both tables same column, so query:

```
select * from games left join game_info using(game_id);
```

will work same as

```
select * from games left join game_info ON games.game_id = game_info.game_id
```

so you could simply use:

```
$games = DB::table('games')
    ->leftJoin('game_info', 'games.game_id','=','game_info.game_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: that says that I am missing argument 2 for `leftJoin`

Comment: Yep, sorry, my mistake, deleting this

Comment: it works the same, yes, but it doesn't return the results the same. Using `on` you will get both `game_id` columns from both table. Using `using` you will get the two columns merged as one.

Comment: Yes, but when you don't specify columns (and you don't do it in sample code), in fact you'll have available `game_id` only once so it won't make you any difference

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn There's one more thing - it seems `USING` is not standard in SQL and it's not available in all engines so probably that's why there's no builder method to create it