# in SQL, why is this JOIN returning the key column twice?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to get my head around it. I'm fairly new to SQL and this behavior would be strange in R or Pandas or other things that I'm used to using.

Basically, I have two tables in two different databases, with a common key `user_id`. I want to join all the columns with

```
SELECT * FROM db1.first_table t1 
JOIN db2.second_table t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Great, it works. Except there are two (identical) columns called `user_id`. This wouldn't really matter, except that I am doing this in pyspark and when I try to export the joined table to a flat file I get an error that two of the columns have the same name. There are work-arounds for this, but I'm just wondering if someone can explain why the join returns *both* `user_id` columns. It seems like it is an inner join so by definition the columns are identical. Why would it return both?

As a side question, is there an easy way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because "select *" is returning all columns from both tables.  IF you need to limit, then explicitly define the table.columns that you want

Comment: because you are using `SELECT *` and that means that it returns every column for every table in the join

Comment: Workaround? Using `select *` is actually not very good practice and you should ALWAYS define which columns you want to retrieve. That is not a workaround - that is the way you should do it!

Comment: My only issue issue, that both tables have literally over 1000 columns. I can list them all, but it will be a bit tedious, not to mention ugly. Can you do SELECT * EXCEPT user_id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SELECT *` returns all columns from all tables of the query.  That includes both `user_id` columns - one from table A, one from table B.

The best practice is to list the column names you want returned specifically, though another option to shorten the list would be:

```
SELECT TableA.*, 
       TableB.col1, 
       TableB.col2, 
       ...rest of B columns except user_id
```

Comment: This cannot possibly be the best way to do this? In data science I often have, like the person who asked this question, 1000+ columns. Good luck listing all of these manually...

Comment: @Thomas In SQL it's the only way. There are plenty of ways to generate a column select without typing them all manually, but the question asked if, "in SQL", there is a way around this behavior, and there is not.

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193410)? `USING` instead of `ON` seems to solve the problem? (Honest question, I am not deep enough into SQL to know any potential pitfalls)

Comment: See also [this excellent and highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367066/4629950)

Comment: @Thomas Those are good points, it's just that `USING` isn't available in all flavors of SQL.  I think your answer is the correct one given the `pyspark` tag.

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers (except the one that OP wrote himself) seem to assume that we are operating on really small tables where we can manually type out every column we need.

The simplest solution in PySpark would be to use the DataFrame join syntax:

```
df = left_df.join(right_df, ["name"])
```

This will not duplicate the column and behave like a pandas merge. If there is no special reason why you have to write it as an sql command, I would recommend this. Contrast this to

```
df = left_df.join(right_df, left.name == right.name)
```

which will behave like a SQL join and keep both columns!

This also applies to Scala and R, [see here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html).

Another solution would be to rename the second target column to something like "target_dataframe2", then joining with sql, then simply dropping "target_dataframe2" again.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Does the spark command return both user_id cols or does it operate more like a pandas merge (i.e. only keep one copy of the join keys)?

Comment: It depends on how you use it: If you use it as described above (just the column name), it behaves like pandas. If you mention both columns like this: `left_df.name == right_df.name`, it will give you both columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using `Select *`. When only `*` is define in after `SELECT`, it return all the columns from both tables. you have to define column names. Always define what columns you want to display. You can do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.ColumnName1, t2.ColumnName2
FROM db1.first_table t1 
INNER JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

`*` can be used in following ways:

Following query will return all columns from both tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.first_table t1 
INNER JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Following query will return all columns from first_table table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM db1.first_table t1 
INNER JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Following query will return all columns from Second_table table:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM db1.first_table t1 
INNER JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Also, you can get all columns from one table and certain columns from other table in this manner:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.ColumnName
FROM db1.first_table t1 
INNER JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the number of field referencing what field you want.

Right now you have

```
  SELECT *
```

that is equal to

```
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
```

Maybe you want something like

```
  SELECT t1.*, t2.field1, t2.field2 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out a way to do this without typing out all of the column names (as I mentioned in the comments, there are ~5k columns total).

This is specific to pyspark, but I just exported the column names to a csv and loaded them in and did the following:

```
with open("t1_cols.csv") as data_file:    
    t1_cols = data_file.read().split('\n')
with open("t2_cols.csv") as data_file:    
    t2_cols = data_file.read().split('\n')

sql = 'SELECT t1.user_id, t1.' + ', t1.'.join(t1_cols) + \
', t2.' + ', t2.'.join(t2_cols) + ' ' + \
'FROM db1.first_table t1 JOIN db2.second_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id'

df = sqlContext.sql(sql)
```

A little obnoxious, but it worked.

Also, I accepted the first answer because all of the above answers are technically correct and that was the first one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one column of user_id to get printed then you should use Inner join with `USING` keyword.

When you use `USING` keyword with a column name, it filters out that common column from both the tables and displays only one. But when you use `ON` with a condition `t1.user_id = t2.user_id` then it's just a coincidence of column with the same name is used in condition.

`ON` is also used to compare different columns of two tables so it does not filter out the columns on the basis of condition. So, if you want to display common columns only once after joining then you should use `USING` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who may arrive at this post now, you may consider '**NATURAL JOIN**' which will **not** return the duplicate fields and you don't need to type in all the column names.

The caveat is that you can only join if the Column name is same in both tables which was true for the OP (user_id).

```
SELECT * FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2;
```

Cheers.

Reference: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-natural-join.php