# filter dynamic tables structure

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

I have the following tables structure :

this table for main categories

[image]

for each category we can add values

[image]

for each category we can add filters for search

[image]

for each filter we can add values

[image]

finally this table is used for saving data to each category value this

[image]

I want to create search query to find results based on user chosen filter value

for example find a university that has sector : public and degree : bachelor?

the search will be done on the last table

for example find a university that has sector : public and degree : bachelor?

the query should handle filter_id = 1 and filter_id_value = 1 also filter_id =2 and filter_id_value =3

the final result should be university of jordan

**NOTE : I program using php and mysql**

Comment: based on  example : find a university that has sector : public and degree : bachelor SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE university like '%$unv%' and degree='bachlor'

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear, I hope that you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

please be more concrete about your issue. What is your current state? Did you do some approaches by yourself? We can't create the complete filter query for you.
Please take a look at [database relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)), especially [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) statements.

But i want to give you an approach. First, you have to determine in which kind your tables are related ([1->1, 1->n, n->n ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling))). In your query, you have to connect your tables via JOINS and their ON statements ([maybe you also could use USING statements, but this rely on your db concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using)). You can check in the WHERE condition if the user input match your records.

I hope you can continue your work with my help!

Comment: the search will be done on the last table

for example find a university that has sector : public and degree : bachelor?

the query should handle filter_id = 1 and filter_id_value = 1 also filter_id =2 and filter_id_value =3

the final result should be university of jordan