# What does ON mean in SQL?

Tags: sql, join

I am just starting to learn `SQL`. Can someone explain what `ON` means in the example?

```
SELECT title, imdb_score
FROM films
JOIN reviews
ON films.id = reviews.film_id
WHERE title = 'To Kill a Mockingbird';
```

Comment: You should probably start with learning joins first: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ON vs USING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using)

Answer (score 2):

> ON films.id = reviews.film_id

To specify `JOIN` condition. With `ON` clause you specify exactly on which column you want to match both table records. You can as well specify extra conditions like

```
ON films.id = reviews.film_id
AND <more condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a join condition.
In your example you will get `title` and `imdb_score` from those rows from `films` and `reviews`, which have the same `id` and `film_id`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-on-clause/

Answer (score 0):

'ON' shows the connection between tables. For your example, the main table is 'films' and you want to bring data from table 'reviews'. If you dont tell computer how to connect data it cant know which movie has which reviews. You are saying that id's are the same for both of this table when you use 'ON'

Answer (score 0):

I would add for better readability, the `ON` right next to the table name you want to join

```
SELECT title, imdb_score
FROM films
JOIN reviews ON films.id = reviews.film_id
WHERE title = 'To Kill a Mockingbird';
```