# Join conditions, intermediate SQL

Tags: sql, join

what's the difference between the join conditions "on" and "using" if both are used to select specified column(s)?

Comment: This is (obviously) a(n absolutely basic easily found) faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ON vs USING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-on-vs-using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using` is just a short-circuit to express the join condition when the related columns have the same name.

Consider the following example:

```
select ...
from orders o
inner join order_items oi on oi.order_id = o.order_id
```

This can be shortened with `using`, as follows:

```
select ...
from orders o
inner join order_items oi using(order_id)
```

Notes:

- this also works when joining on several columns having identical names
- parentheses are mandatory with `using`

Answer (score 1):

The main difference with `using` is that the columns for the `join` have to have the same names.  This is generally a good practice anyway in the data model.

Another important difference is that the columns come from different tables -- the `join` condition doesn't specify the tables (some people view this as a weakness, but you'll see it is quite useful).

A handy feature is that the common columns used for the `join` are removed when you use `select *`.  So

```
select *
from a join
     b
     on a.x = b.x
```

will result in `x` appearing twice in the result set.  This is not allowed for subqueries or views.  On the other hand, this query only has `x` once in the result set.

```
select *
from a join
     b
     using (x)
```

Of course, other columns could be duplicated.

For an outer join, the value is the non-`NULL` value, if any.  This becomes quite handy for `full join`s:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     using (x) full join
     c
     using (x);
```

Because of the `null` values, expressing this without `using` is rather cumbersome:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     on b.x = a.x full join
     c
     on c.x = coalesce(a.x, b.x);
```