# Concise SQL for joining many tables on a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have about 122 tables that all share a particular column. Is there an elegant/concise method to join all of these tables on that column without having 121 instances of

join on A.id = B.id

in the query?

Comment: Just wondering: what is the design of your database and what is the question you need to answer that requires such a query? I've thought limits on `JOUN`ed tables in DBMSes are unreachable

Comment: And just to copypaste condition you can use [`USING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) keyword in `JOIN`

Comment: [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) data model?

Comment: If you need to join 121 tables you need 121 JOIN conditions. But this sounds like a rather strange data model if that is necessary

Answer (score 0):

If the column in question has the same name in both tables (which it should) then you can use this shorter syntax:

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (column)
```

The column will also appear only once in the result, instead of being present for each table. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366006/mysql-join-on-vs-using).

You will still have to do it for each table, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your solution:

**Create table and insert statement:**

```
create table splitUpdate (no int,productname varchar(10),productcrossell varchar(20));
insert into splitUpdate values (1,'a','a(1)');
insert into splitUpdate values (2,null,'c(4),d(5)');
insert into splitUpdate values (3,null,'Z(1),b(2)');

create table eleminate (product varchar(20));
insert into eleminate values('x');
insert into eleminate values('y');
insert into eleminate values('Z');
insert into eleminate values('z');
```

**Update Query:**

```
with cte as (
    select no,productname,p.product,row_number()over(partition by no)rn ,substring(p.product  from 1 for position('(' in p.product )-1) SplittedProduct
from splitupdate t, unnest(string_to_array(t.productcrossell ,','))p(product)
where substring(p.product  from 1 for position('(' in p.product )-1) not in (select product from eleminate))
update splitupdate set productname=splittedproduct 
from cte 
where splitupdate.productname is null and splitupdate.no=cte.no and cte.rn=1
```

**SplitUpdate Table before updating:**

```
|no|productname|productcrossell| 
|1 |a          |a(1)           |
|2 |c          |c(4),d(5)      |
|3 |b          |Z(1),b(2)      |
```

**Result:**

```
|no|productname|productcrossell| 
|1 |a          |a(1)           |
|2 |c          |c(4),d(5)      |
|3 |b          |Z(1),b(2)      |
```