# Inconsistency with MySQL - USING vs ON

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and was taught that the USING clause is a much simpler method of comparing two columns from different tables than the ON clause. After learning this I decided to download the example database from mysqltutorial.com and began experimenting. Not long after, I noticed inconsistencies. The number of outputted rows is vastly different. The query using the ON clause outputs 122 rows while the query with the USING clause outputs 326 total rows. Below are the two queries that outputted different results.

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders USING(customerNumber)

SELECT *
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
```

Is this issue user-error or is USING and ON much different that I originally thought?

Comment: please update your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table customers;` and `show create table orders;`

Comment: @SalmanA I'd thought using was nonstandard too, but others here have asserted otherwise

Comment: @raina77ow nothing I see in that question would explain this difference in rows

Comment: Note as well an answer in the linked question which explicitly states that [phpMyAdmin returns erroneous results from USING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750211/1786065).

Comment: @ysth yes looks like it _is_ part of sql92. But I've used sql for 18 years without using `using`

Comment: I would definitely regard 'USING' as non standard, have used sql for a similar length of time to @SalmanA and also never having heard of it!

Comment: You can use `USING`  when both the tables share a column of the exact same name on which they join. If you run both queries from terminal you would get the same result. Personally I never use phpmyadmin.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: "mysqltutorial.com" is just an advertiser showing a list of links; can you provide the actual source for your example database?

Comment: `USING` is definitely standard SQL, and I use it pretty regularly. The columns must exist by the same name in both tables, and the join expression you intend to use must be equality (`=`).

Comment: The two join forms do behave the same. I would assume you are making a mistake in your observation. Either querying different data, or else the data has changed between your tests. You need to show a reproducible case (hopefully a dbfiddle) that demonstrates a difference.

Comment: I used the mysql command line interface with my MAMP installation and the result set count from the INNER JOIN ON and the INNER JOIN USING was the same at 326 rows. Looks like PHPmyAdmin is jacked up with its INNER JOIN implementation.

Comment: @deep64blue `USING` is standard, it is defined in ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 ("SQL:2016"), in section 7.10 <joined table>, and it has been in the standard at least since SQL-92.