# Alternative of Natural Join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the alternative or syntax for Natural Join in SQL SERVER.

Comment: Use an inner join http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696383/difference-between-natural-join-and-inner-join or maybe you're after [using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370268/whats-the-difference-between-using-and-on-in-table-joins)

Comment: Don't do natural join when programming. If a column with same name later is added to one of the tables, the join will quit working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is **no** natural JOIN in Sql Server. Also check [SQL Server - lack of NATURAL JOIN / x JOIN y USING(field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277580/sql-server-lack-of-natural-join-x-join-y-usingfield)

Comment: Sir, I know there is no Natural Join in SQL, That's way i am asking for alternative for natural join

Comment: @AhmadMurtaza:- You can use Inner Join. But without getting your exact issue it is hard to say how you can use it. More importantly we would like to know what you are trying to achive?