# Prefix in field name SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am an extreme rookie when it comes to SQL and I am trying to self teach myself.  I have a few questions regarding SQL and writing queries:

1. I've been given some examples of queries by a colleague and many of them have the field names beginning with either m. or t. or o.email (eg. m.email or t.email or o.email).  What do the prefixes indicate?
2. I am attempting to write a JOIN query but keep receiving an error message saying: *An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'*  What would cause this? Neither of the data extensions I am trying to join contain boonlean fields.

I've written it as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, status_type, status_value_text FROM ent.[Table 1] JOIN [Table 2] ON email
```

Again, I am extremely new, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answers to your questions won't really change, but the `[]` syntax on `[Table 1]` suggests you are not using MySQL, but rather a Microsoft database like Access or SQL Server. (unless you included those as placeholders). Can you tag your question with the database you are really using?

Comment: Sorry! Thank-you for comment.  SQL Server is the correct database.

Answer (score 1):

> What do the prefixes indicate?

If you look at the `FROM` clause of the example queries you are questioning, you should notice table *aliases* specified after the full table names. Aliases are used sometimes just to shorten the table names from needing to be fully spelled out, but most often they are needed to disambiguate between similarly named columns in more than one of the tables in the `FROM`.

```
SELECT
  -- Get the email column from the table aliased
  -- as `m` (table1)
  m.email
FROM
  -- table1 aliased as m
  table1 AS m
  -- table1 aliased as e
  INNER JOIN table2 AS e ON....
```

Consider two related tables, `table1` and `table2`. Both of them has a column called `email`.   In the `SELECT` list, you may not specify merely `email` because the RDBMS won't know which one you want. Instead, you must qualify it with the table name. Since the tables were aliased as `m, e` in the `FROM`, you must use the alias in `SELECT` instead of the full table name.

[MS SQL Server documentation on table aliases...](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

In your join's `ON` clause, you simply supplied the column name `email`, which we can assume is a common value relating the two tables.  A join's `ON` clause expects a boolean expression wherein a *true* value doing a row-wise comparison between the tables results in a row being returned.

So the `ON` clause needs a boolean expression with two sides, or something returning TRUE. In your case, it is equality between the `email` columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   -- Must qualify email since both tables have it
   -- Using the full table name, or its alias if an alias
   -- was provided in `FROM`.
   [Table 1].email,
   status_type,
   status_value_text
FROM 
  ent.[Table 1]
  -- Equality between email columns completes the join
  JOIN [Table 2] ON [Table 1].email = [Table 2].email
```

The expression in `ON` can be *anything* which evaluates to `TRUE`. It need not be an exact match between column values, though an exact match is by far the most common use case.  You could say for example `ON 1 = 1`, which is *always* true. The resultant rowset would match every row from `[Table 1]` to every row of `[Table 2]` (which is a cartesian product). It could also be `ON 1 = 2` which is *never* true, and therefore basically pointless since it would never return rows.

Using a syntax similar to the `ON email` you attempted, some RDBMS systems support a `USING()` in place of `ON`, allowing you to specify the equal column instead of a boolean expression. You might therefore also express it as

```
FROM 
  ent.[Table 1]
  JOIN [Table 2] USING (email)
```

See also [What's the difference between `ON` and `USING`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370268/541091)

Comment: Hello thank-you for your note.  I tried writing SELECT DISTINCT email AS Email, status_type AS BabyDobOrDue, status_value_text FROM ent.[table 1] a JOIN ent.[table 2] b ON a.email = b.email but the error I received was "Query field.Ambiguous column name 'email’."  Do you know what would case that?

Comment: @psimp That is due to the missing alias, assuming both tables have an `email` column. As in my top example, you will need its alias `SELECT DISTINCT a.email AS Email....` (or `b.email` if appropriate, but in this case it should not matter).

Answer (score 1):

The general form of an SQL `SELECT` query is:

```
SELECT (columns, expressions, aggregate functions)
FROM (data sources)
WHERE (filters on data sources)
GROUP BY (columns used to group the data, needed if you use aggregate functions)
HAVING (filters on data AFTER it's grouped)
```

About the `FROM` clause, if you use more than one data source (table or view), you should think how your data will be related:

1. A cross join returns the cartesian product of the tables involved.

   Example:

   `FROM foo, bar` will return all the rows of table `foo` and all the rows from table `bar`, without any rule on how they are related.
2. An inner join returns only the data that fulfills a relation rule.

   Example:

   `FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.aField = bar.aField` (alternative: `FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.aField = b.aField`) will return only the rows of `foo` and `bar` that fulfils the condition provided (the field `aField` in each table must match). **Important:** An `INNER JOIN` must have a boolean expression, i.e. the relation must either be true or false; most times it will be an equality relationship (`=`) but it can be anything that returns a `TRUE/FALSE` value (`>`, `<`, `>=`, etcetera).
3. An outer join returns the full data of one table and only the rows of the other table that match the relation rule (for any other non-matching row of the first table, the columns from the second table will have a `NULL` value).

   There are two possible outer joins: `LEFT JOIN` will return all the rows from the table on the left of the relation rule, and only the matching rows of the right table of the relation. `RIGHT JOIN` does just the opposite.

   Example:

   `FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.aField = bar.aField`

   As it was the case with the `INNER JOIN`, the relation must have a boolean expression.

Now, as you've noticed, you need to tell the system from which field you're getting the data. That's the reason for the "prefixes": They are the table (or schema.database.table) names. If you want, you can use *aliases* on this table names (just as you can use aliases on fields):

Example: `FROM foo AS f INNER JOIN bar AS b on f.aField = b.aField`

The aliases used in the `FROM` clause must be used every time you use the field in the same `SELECT` query.

Now, talking explicitly about your query: The `JOIN` in your post is missing the relation rule: You're telling the database server that the tables are related, but you're not defining the relation rule. Wich fields must match? Complete the `JOIN` expression with the columns that must match between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

1. The m. or t. are aliases for tables within your query (so you are probably using tables that begin with the letter m and t). The alias is specified after the table name in the FROM part of your query.
2. The syntax looks off for your JOIN. The query should probably look more similar to this:

> SELECT DISTINCT t1.email, t1.status_type, t2.status_value_text
>   FROM
>   [Table 1] t1 JOIN [Table 2] t2 ON t1.email = t2.email

Check out this link to see more examples.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp